# Replicated Nginx in Docker container not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

To start off, I've been working with Docker and Nginx for about 2 months now.

I am working on 2 projects that share a similar parent project. Both projects serve different functions (my client and their members) and both projects do not interact with each other directly in any way.

So, both projects have this structure:

```
|-- Docker Container 0 (Nginx)
     |-- Docker Container 1 (Django)
     |-- Docker Container 2 (Django)
     |-- Docker Container 3 (Django)
     |-- ...
```

My problem is when I replicate "[Project A] Docker Container 0 (Nginx)" to Project B, I cannot connect to Nginx. Both Container 0's are running on the same machine, using different container names. Both are using different ports, Project A is using 7682 and Project B is 7683.

Now, there are no problems connecting to Project A, however replicating Project A's container as Project B, I now cannot connect to it. Even while killing and deleting the entire Project A, I still cannot connect to Project B using a domain name, but using an IP it works.

https://www.example1.com:7683/members/ => Does not work
 https://200.18.0.2:7683/members/ => Works

I should note that an SSL/TLS certificate is installed, but that's not the problem. I removed the SSL/TLS connection config from Nginx to use port 80 and it still isn't working.

Also, both Project's Container 0's Nginx config is using the server_name www.example1.com, just on different ports exposed by Docker.

Any idea what could cause such a problem?

Comment: If it can't even connect i would guess the host name for project B does not resolve at all or resolves to the wrong IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my problem.

I did not allow port 7683 access from the cloud instance console I was running it from.

Always remember to check port access if you're running on a cloud instance, even when accessing said port from within.